# How share folder in QEMU with plan9/virtfs between MacOS host and Linux guest?

Tags: macos, folders, sharing, virtualization

I am trying to run a Linux Debian with qemu with MacOS Big Sur host.

Unfortunately **virtfs** doesn't work on Mac and there is no easy alternative that I have found.

Is there a way to share folders with plan9?

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

This is what I need: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/122420
but it is still in progress !!

Thanks to all!

Comment: Do you mean plan9 or Linux they are different operating systems

Comment: @mmmmmm I mean this https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup

Comment: For Linux on VMs on macOS I would look at Parallels or Docker which work on Intel or ARM or VMWare or Virtual Box for Intel only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I need: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/122420

Thanks to all!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

As of March 2022, [9pfs is available in QEMU on macOS](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/a70f2f6967e4459a921a947ab5060d3af8034853) if you're using homebrew. My qemu-system-x86_64 command includes the following parameter:

```
-virtfs local,path=/Users/gsf/Downloads,security_model=none,mount_tag=Downloads
```

And my /etc/fstab in the guest includes this line:

```
Downloads /home/gsf/Downloads 9p _netdev,trans=virtio,version=9p2000.u,msize=104857600 0 0
```

With `security_model=none` I did have to modify user and group IDs in the guest to match the host. You may prefer `security_model=mapped` instead.

Also I tried `version=9p2000.L` but that resulted in "Network dropped connection on reset" errors when trying to access the shared directory. For more info on my full setup, see my [Ubuntu VM on macOS with QEMU](https://gist.github.com/gsf/c7bb24178700ffcaeab9c100c63264bb).

For a documentation of 9pfs from QEMU, visit [here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup).

Comment: I'm using this right now, but I'm using the xml configuration for libvirt <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='mapped'>
    <source dir='/.../test'/>
    <target dir='hostshare'/>
</filesystem>. If you have any idea, where do I change the user and group, because on the mac guest it sets both user and group to 1000, which is the id of my current user.

Answer (score 5):

As of July 2021, `9pfs` and `virtfs` are not available in QEMU on macOS.

An alternate method to share folders with *read-write* access from a macOS host to a Linux VM is to use `sshfs`.

###### Read-write access using SSHFS

1. Install `sshfs` on Linux VM.
2. Allow [remote login](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp1066/mac) on macOS host: `System Preferences > Sharing > Remote login`.
3. Mount macOS directory on Linux VM via:

```
sshfs user@macos_ip:/Users/user/mydir ~/host_mydir
```

If you cannot use ssh to access the macOS host you can still share the directory with *read-only* access using QEMU [virtual FAT disk images](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/images.html#virtual-fat-disk-images):

###### Read-only access using a virtual FAT disk image

1. Add directory as a disk image via:

**Note:** VM will not start without `fat:rw:`

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -machine type=q35,accel=hvf \
  -cpu host \
  -hda /images/linux.qcow2 \
  -drive file=fat:rw:/Users/user/mydir,format=raw,media=disk
```

2. Mount directory in Linux VM via:

**Note:** directory will not mount without `-o ro`

```
# 'ro' is required to mount directory
sudo mount -t auto -o ro /dev/sdb1 /media
```

This method has some ***limitations***:

- [never] use non-ASCII filenames
- [never] use “-snapshot” together with “:rw:”
- [never] expect it to work when loadvm’ing
- [never] write to the FAT directory on the host system while accessing it with the guest system